# while cloning git repository in windows show error : unable to create temporary file: No such file or directory

Tags: git, gitlab, git-bash, atlassian-sourcetree, smartgit

In windows while cloning git repository show error unable to create temporary file: No such file or directory, fatal: failed to write object,
fatal: unpack-objects failed
I tried different different software sourcetree,smartgit and git-bash also but everyone show same error

```
git -c filter.lfs.smudge= -c filter.lfs.required=false
    -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false
    -c credential.helper=manager-st
    clone --branch master --recursive
    https://narendra910512@gitlab.com/arun.mondal/PostgresProcess.git
    "E:\Collectcent Projects\PostgresProcess"
Cloning into 'E:\Collectcent Projects\PostgresProcess'...
error: unable to create temporary file: No such file or directory
fatal: failed to write object
fatal: unpack-objects failed
Completed with errors, see above.
```

I tried so much but can't find any solution.

Comment: Do you have `TEMP` environment variable properly configured?

Comment: Does the repository contain files and/or folders that have spaces at the start or end of their filename?

Comment: @mstrap i have TEMP environment variable set to Appdata/local

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen  No its not contain any file or folder which have spaces at start or end. Actually repository will cloned on other system normally. Only on my windows os show this problem

Comment: Can you run this command on the command prompt and paste the result into your question? `SET TEMP`

Comment: Perhaps it should be `E:/...` if you are working with git bash?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen i run the command SET TEMP it show TEMP = C:\users\HP\AppData\Local\temp and TEMPDIR = TEMP = C:\users\HP\AppData\Local\temp

Comment: You have verified that the folder exists?

Comment: yeah temp folder exists in AppData\local

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem when adding files to the repository. Just found a solution that worked for me. I changed the fscache config to False.

```
git config --global core.fscache false
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: I have done this before putting the question but not worked in my case